# Java Multiple instance of child class not creating instance of baseclass

Tags: inheritance

I am trying to write an application for map navigation. It is supposed to take txt data files as input and convert them into lists and display them accordingly. The problem i am facing is that i created a baseclass called Distance and a childclass which extends Distance called location. In the distance class there is a variable of point(another class i made) which records the coordinates of the location itself. Distance also has a method which calculates the distance between the current location and the point passed to it in argument. Now the trouble is, after creating multiple instances of class location, the class distance is recording only 1 set of values in the point variable, as if the class distance is only being instantiated once.

I am attatching the code:

```
public class Distance {
private static Point point1;
private static Point point2;

Distance(Point coords){
    point1=coords;
    System.out.println("cons 1 long: "+point1.longitude);
    System.out.println("cons 1 lat: "+point1.latitude);
}

public  double calcDistance(Point coords2){
    point2=coords2;
    double theta;

    System.out.println("point 1 long: "+point1.longitude);
    System.out.println("point 2 long: "+point2.longitude);

    if(Double.compare(point1.longitude,point2.longitude)>0){
     theta = point1.longitude - point2.longitude;
     System.out.println(point1.longitude+"-"+point2.longitude);
    }else{
        theta = point2.longitude - point1.longitude;
        System.out.println(point2.longitude+"-"+point1.longitude);
    }
    System.out.println(theta);

    double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(point1.latitude)) 
                * Math.sin(deg2rad(point2.latitude)) 
                + Math.cos(deg2rad(point1.latitude)) 
                * Math.cos(deg2rad(point2.latitude)) 
                * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
    System.out.println(dist);

      dist = Math.acos(dist);
      System.out.println(dist);
      dist = rad2deg(dist);
      System.out.println(dist);
      dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
      System.out.println(dist);
      dist = dist * 1.609344;
      System.out.println(dist);
    dist = (double) Math.round(dist * 100.0) / 100.0;
    System.out.println(dist);
    return dist;

}

private static double deg2rad(double deg) {
      return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }
private static double rad2deg(double rad) {
      return (rad * 180 / Math.PI);
    }
```

}

btw, the formula works fine.

This is the location class:

```
import java.util.List;
public class Location extends Distance{

public  String name;
public Point coord;
public  List<String> connections;

Location(String nam, Point coords, List<String> connect){
    super(coords);
    name=nam;
    coord=coords;
    connections=connect;

}
```

}

and this is where the txt file is being read and put into list array.

```
public List<Location> processLocations(){
    List<Location> locations= new ArrayList<Location>();

    for (String location : locationData){
        String[] data=location.split("____");

        String name=data[0];
        Point coord=new Point(Double.parseDouble(data[1]),Double.parseDouble(data[2]));


        List<String> connections= new ArrayList<String>();

        for(String connect: connectionsData){
            String[] con=connect.split("____");
            //System.out.println(con[0]+name);
            if(con[0].equals(name)){
                connections.add(con[1]);
            }
        }

        Location loc=new Location(name,coord,connections);
        locations.add(loc);
    }//for location ends
    return locations;
}//process location ends
```

If i access the location.coords variable, it gives the correct points for the given location. but if i access point1 of distance class, it gives the same coords for all the locations.

Comment: Here's your problem `private static Point point1;` remove the static keyword, I think you should know why.

Comment: @snajahi Holy mother of overlooking :p Thank you soo much for the help.